# PostgreSQL: Efficiently split JSON array into rows

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table (Table A) that includes a text column that contains JSON encoded data.

The JSON data is always an array with between one and a few thousand plain object.

I have another table (Table B) with a few columns, including a column with a datatype of 'JSON'

I want to select all the rows from table A, split the json array into its elements and insert each element into table B

Bonus objective: Each object (almost) always has a key, `x`. I want to pull the value of `x` out into column, and delete `x` from the original object (if it exists).

E.g.: Table A

```
| id | json_array (text)              |
+----+--------------------------------+
|  1 | '[{"x": 1}, {"y": 8}]'         |
|  2 | '[{"x": 2, "y": 3}, {"x": 1}]' |
|  3 | '[{"x": 8, "z": 2}, {"z": 3}]' |
|  4 | '[{"x": 5, "y": 2, "z": 3}]'   |
```

...would become: Table B

```
| id | a_id | x    | json (json)        |
+----+------+------+--------------------+
|  0 |    1 |    1 | '{}'               |
|  1 |    1 | NULL | '{"y": 8}'         |
|  2 |    2 |    2 | '{"y": 3}'         |
|  3 |    2 |    1 | '{}'               |
|  4 |    3 |    8 | '{"y": 2}'         |
|  5 |    3 | NULL | '{"z": 3}'         |
|  6 |    4 |    5 | '{"y": 2, "z": 3}' |
```

This initially has to work on a few million rows, and would then need to be run at regular intervals, so making it efficient would be a priority.

Is it possible to do this without using a loop and PL/PgSQL? I haven't been making much progress.

Comment: Can you use `jsonb` (i.e. PG9.5)? The `json` data type is not good for manipulating the object, where `jsonb` has many more options. Deleting `x` is easy with `jsonb`, more complicated with `json`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `json` data type is not particularly suitable (or intended) for modification at the database level. Extracting `"x"` objects from the JSON object is therefore cumbersome, although it can be done.

You should create your table B (with hopefully a more creative column name than `"json"`; I am using `item` here) and make the `id` column a `serial` that starts at 0. A **pure `json` solution** then looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO b (a_id, x, item)
  SELECT sub.a_id, sub.x,
         ('{' ||
         string_agg(
             CASE WHEN i.k IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '"' || i.k || '":' || i.v END,
             ', ') ||
         '}')::json
  FROM (
    SELECT a.id AS a_id, (j.items->>'x')::integer AS x, j.items
    FROM a, json_array_elements(json_array) j(items) ) sub
  LEFT JOIN json_each(sub.items) i(k,v) ON i.k <> 'x'
  GROUP BY sub.a_id, sub.x
  ORDER BY sub.a_id;
```

In the sub-query this extracts the `a_id` and `x` values, well as the JSON object. In the outer query the JSON object is broken into its individual pieces and the objects with key `x` thrown out (the `LEFT JOIN ON i.k <> 'x'`). In the select list the pieces are put back together again with string concatenation and grouped into compound objects.

This necessarily has to be like this because `json` has no built-in manipulation functions of any consequence. This works on PG versions 9.3+, i.e. since time immemorial insofar as JSON support is concerned.

**If you are using PG9.5+**, the solution is much simpler through a cast to `jsonb`:

```
INSERT INTO b (a_id, x, item)
  SELECT a.id, (j.items->>'x')::integer, j.items #- '{x}'
  FROM a, jsonb_array_elements(json_array::jsonb) j(items);
```

The `#-` operator on the `jsonb` data type does all the dirty work here. Obviously, there is a lot of work going on behind the scenes, converting `json` to `jsonb`, so if you find that you need to manipulate your JSON objects more frequently then you are better off using the `jsonb` type to begin with. In your case I suggest you do some benchmarking with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ...` (you can safely forget about the `INSERT` while testing) on perhaps 10,000 rows to see which works best for your setup.

Comment: We aren't on 9.5 yet unfortunately, but hopefully it won't be long. Thanks so much for the comprehensive answer.