# postgresql triggers to insert json data into columns and keep left over fields

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, triggers, insert

I have found this question [PostgreSQL: Efficiently split JSON array into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39051905/12603110)
I have a similar situation but for inserts instead.
Considering I do not have a table but raw json in a ndjson file...

```
{"x": 1}
{"x": 2, "y": 3}
{"x": 8, "z": 3}
{"x": 5, "y": 2, "z": 3}
```

I want to insert the data into a table of the form (where json fields which do not have a column are stored in the json column)

| x | y | json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 3 | NULL |
| 8 | NULL | {"z": 3} |
| 5 | 2 | {"z": 3} |

How do I define my table such that postgresql does it automatically on insert or \copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the operator `->` and cast the value to the proper type for values of existing regular columns. Use the delete operator to get the remaining JSON values.

I have used CTE in the example. Instead, create the table `json_data` with a single JSONB column and copy the JSON file to it with `\copy`

```sql
with json_data(json) as (
values
    ('{"x": 1}'::jsonb),
    ('{"x": 2, "y": 3}'),
    ('{"x": 8, "z": 3}'),
    ('{"x": 5, "y": 2, "z": 3}')
)

select 
    (json->'x')::int as x, 
    (json->'y')::int as y, 
    nullif(json- 'x'- 'y', '{}') as json
from json_data
```

Read about [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in the documentation.

Note. In Postgres 10 or earlier use the `->>` operator instead of `->`.

---

To automate the conversion when importing json data, define a trigger:

```sql
create table json_data(json jsonb);

create or replace function json_data_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    insert into target_table
    select
        (new.json->>'x')::int, 
        (new.json->>'y')::int, 
        nullif(new.json- 'x'- 'y', '{}');
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger json_data_trigger
before insert on json_data
for each row execute procedure json_data_trigger();
```

Test it in [Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e61472e0901a633ab209c07a1d6bec27)

Comment: I am aware of this article: https://konbert.com/blog/import-json-into-postgres-using-copy I want something to also work on insertion time. not just from already existing table

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I tried it on Fiddle. the solution works perfectly. I just changed return new to return NULL so I don't have duplicate data!

Comment: @YoraiLevi - Good idea with `return null`, then `json_data` acts like a pipe.